# ClickOnce is not updating a DLL on client machine when there's a new version

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clickonce

I'm running into an issue with my ClickOnce deployment after updating to a new version of a third-party managed library which consists of multiple DLLs. The version numbers in the metadata of the DLLs were all incremented even though one of the DLLs has no actual code changes. Now ClickOnce seems to be re-using a cached copy of the old DLL on the client machine, probably because both the new and old version hash to the same value (despite the metadata showing different version numbers). This results in a runtime error:

"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I set "Hash" to "Exclude" for this DLL in the ClickOnce "Application Files" settings in order to try to force the DLL to be updated, and this solved the problem. However, this means that I can no longer sign the application, which is an issue.

Does anyone know of another way to handle this situation?